# match a word with out consecutive characters in it

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am new to java regex. Can you please give a matching pattern for the following requirement.
Example:
"Apple"  or "Google"  should not be matched since there are consecutive characters in them.
But, words like "Hard2Crack"  or  "Sometimes"  should match.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: At least try something to indicate some effort on your part

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sL6bX8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!.*?([a-z])\1)^.*$
```

You can try this.uses a negative looakahead.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/13